# Fragment (swipe) and Button listener issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

First of all excuse my stupid knowledge of android, because I'm new in it.
We have some codes here that changes tabs with swipe gesture with 3 Fragments that named:  "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies".
[This is the source codes](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)
[image]
Here is MainActivity activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

With this adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

This is main xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

One of Fragments (others are like this)

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

With this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff8400" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Design Games Screen"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now we want to add a button in this page see this XML:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff8400" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Design Games Screen"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

One way to do this is define button and listener in GamesFragment.java
that is impossible, because it can't be define in that class.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do some thing
            }
        });
```

Second way is merge GameFragment java codes with main codes. And edit main activity like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main & R.layout.fragment_games);
```

That I can't write codes correctly.

Third way is we should write our fragments in main activity that use one layout.

Now can u help me to solve this?

Comment: It seems your first approach is correct, I'm not sure what you mean but it's not possible because it can't be defined there. In onCreateView if you use rootView.findViewById(R.id.button) then you'll have access to the button.

Also in your sample xml you have the id as button and in your sample code you have the id as button1.

Comment: The major issue is not name of button. Any way I will edit them. I used rootView.findViewById(R.id.button) but did not anything changed.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you explained what exactly is not working. Are you getting exceptions? Is the button not accepting touches?

Comment: Sorry i had to write that after View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

Answer (score 0):

```
final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // How to start a new activity form here?????
        }
    });
```

This worked quite well.